# How to remove welcome message specific for logged in user in Magento?

Tags: magento, header, magento-1.7

I only wish to show "Welcome to store!" all of the time, for logged out and also logged in users.

Right now, when a user is logged in, it says "Welcome, firstname lastname!".
Also, when logged in and showing this welcome message, another link shows up saying, "(Not firstname lastname?)"

I want to remove those two things from the header.

I went to **/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php** and changed this bit of code at the very end of the file:

```
public function getWelcome()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
        if (Mage::isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
        } else {
            $this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
        }
    }

    return $this->_data['welcome'];
}
```

Changed that to this:

```
public function getWelcome()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
        $this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
    }
    return $this->_data['welcome'];
}
```

I thought this would do the trick, and it did when the user logs in. But I think when the user ticks the "Remember Me []" when logging in, that this causes the message that says "Welcome, firstname lastname!" to still show up.

I'm at a loss now, I'm not sure how to prevent this "Welcome logged in user" and "Not this user?" message to go away - I only want the normal "Welcome to Store!" message to **always** show.

Comment: did you try altering the design file?

Comment: @utility elaborate, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could accomplish this by:

1) Using CSS to hide it

in /skin/frontend/default/[theme]/css/styles.css search for class “.header .welcome-msg“ (or add to the end of file)

```
.header .welcome-msg {
   display:none;
}
```

2) Remove code from template file

In \app\design\frontend\default[theme]\template\page\html\header.phtml

Remove

```
<p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome()?></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, R.S. This was useful, and I've made my changes properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to look in your template files and remove it.

In my template app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/html/header.phtml there's the following code:

```
<div class="block-welcome-header">
 <h2 class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></h2>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

To remove the 'Not first name, last name' I just removed the call to getAdditionalHtml();

```
<div class="block-welcome-header">
   <h2 class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome() ?> <?php //echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></h2>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```